# How to open a videofile via tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code

```
    from tkinter import filedialog
    .... Some code ......
    self.askfile = filedialog.askopenfile()
```

Can you show me how to open video formats such as (avi, flv, mp4)

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the video file?  Tkinter has no built-in ability to display video at all.  If you just want to select a file to pass on to some other video-capable utility, you've basically done that already (although you'd probably want to use `.askopenfilename()` rather than `.askopenfile()`).

Comment: Actually, my app should open a video. For example, I have one button, and if I press this button, my PC should open a window, and then I can select this video like this. I cannot fill this line completele. filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir.....). Can you show me? Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.